# Android TextView.setText does not work as expected

Tags: android, textview

**I configured a simple single TextView layout (see below after the code) to change the display changing from 10 up to 20. What I see is "20" being displayed. My code is as follows. Want to know why only the last number ("20") is displayed omitting the intermediate ones(10 thru 19))

```
package com.example.test;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    public TextView mytv;
    public Toast mtoast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int i = 10;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        mytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myhw);

        mtoast = Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        while (i++ < 20) {
            mtoast.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            mtoast.show();
            mytv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**The relevant layout is as follows.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myhw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

because the view is not shown until `onResume` call and after that the activity is displayed, all you are doing is changing the view content in `onCreate` method, after `onCreate` activity goes to `onStart` and `onResume` so when `onCreate` finishes the textView value is 20 and after `onResume` it sets the value to 20.
for more information look at activity life cycle at :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Even further: A `Thread.sleep` is not the proper way to update a GUI and watch how it changes. The value it will take is the last one. The activity will be blocked until the last is shown.

If you want to see that effect, you should programm a Thread which communicates the main thread every X seconds, and the main thread should listen the Thread to change it.

For example, you could use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and use onProgressUpdate.

Edited with some code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    /* Running AsyncTask */
    myAsyncTask bkg = new myAsyncTask();
    /* I'll pass an integer parameter: milliseconds to wait. */
    bkg.execute(3000);

}

    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        /* TODO: Do BEFORE background process */
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I'm going to do a background task!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... parameters) {
        /* TODO: What to do in Background */

        /* Retrieving parameter passed */

        int milliseconds = parameters[0];

        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
            publishProgress(milliseconds); /* Will prompt that value */
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERROR";
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (i++ < 20) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
                publishProgress(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "ERROR";
            }

        }
        return "OK";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        /* TODO: After execution of thread */
        if(result.equals("OK"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Correctly Processed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(result.equals("ERROR"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        /* TODO: Here you can access UI elements as your TextView */
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvExample);
        tv.setText(values[0]+"");

    }
}
}
```

**layout/main_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.myapplication2.app.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/whatever">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvExample" />
```

Comment: My formatting is quite bad I know hahaha. Just that HTML editing drives me crazy x.x

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't sleep the UI thread in the first place.

What you probably want to do is to use another thread, let it sleeps for a couple of seconds and, each time you update the UI, use the UI (main) thread. You can do it in several ways, but the simples probably is using an `AsyncTask`, as:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public TextView mytv;
    public Toast mtoast;
    private int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        i = 10;
        mytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myhw);
        mtoast = Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                while (i < 20) {
                    publishProgress(String.valueOf(i));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                mtoast.setText(values[0]);
                mtoast.show();
                mytv.setText(values[0]);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code (tested on device) provided below:

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

```
 private Handler mHandler;

public TextView mytv;

private int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_toast_showing_acounter);
    mytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myhw);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    i = 10;
    scheduleHandler();
}

private void scheduleHandler() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showCounter();
            if (i < 20) {
                scheduleHandler();
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
}

private void showCounter() {
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mytv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    i++;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Want to know why only the last number ("20") is displayed omitting the intermediate ones(10 thru 19))

1. It doesn't work because you sleep the UI Thread.
2. To make this work, you would have to do it through a Thread, you can use an `AsyncTask` for this, or a `Timer` object as i specified below, anyways i recommend the use of `AsyncTask`.

Once i was doing something simmilar, you could use a Timer object for this.

Using the method: `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`

The [Docs for this method says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution, beginning after the specified delay.

It means after the seconds from the second parameter, it will start, using the third parameter as delay for each execution. You will have to cancel it, calling the method:`cancel();`

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (counter == 20) {
                            timer.cancel();
                            counter = 0;
                            time.setText("Ta-da! I'm Done ");
                        }else{
                            counter += 1;
                            if (time != null)
                                time.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, delay, period);
```